# Monitoring progress within xargs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xargs

Is there any way to track or monitor progress within `xargs`?

I'm replacing a `for` loop with `find … | xargs` for performance (specifically to run tasks in parallel). I've read that `parallel` has a progress flag, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this strictly using `xargs`.

I'm also aware that tasks run in parallel via `xargs` will not necessarily finish in the correct order, which compounds the complexity of monitoring progress. Even if a solution would give me a general idea of the progress, that would be a great start.

Comment: progress in terms of number of files?

Comment: My impression is that `xargs` gets some attention with new features. So what may be true in one OS/version environment may not be true in your current environment. Did you read carefully your `man xargs`? Also, just using a properly constructed `ps` cmd (again, `man ps`), might give you a lot of clues. My current os has `pstee` which could be helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'd like to monitor progress in terms of number of files processed (percentage completed). I'm running a large number of images through a compression process. I am also running OS X, which has a fairly limited version of `xargs` installed.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to input how many lines you roughly already processed you may create simple shell function to do that

```
#!/bin/bash

#-----
##
## @function count
##
## @desc Write every n'th number (if n is 5 write 5, 10, 15, ...)
##
## @param $1 - number 
##
#-----
function count {
   typeset C=0
   while read L; do
      C=$(( C + 1 ))
      if [ $(( $C % $1 )) -eq 0 ]; then
         echo $C 1>&2
      fi
      echo "$L"
   done
}

find . | count 100 | xargs ...
```

Small problem is that this prints number of lines passed to xargs, not number of lines already processed by the command invoked by xargs. Plus every pipe has some buffer, so it will show slightly higher number than it should. On my machine it showed ~500 lines in advance to real state but if you are processing sufficiently large number of lines 500 is negligible :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for just a general indication of progress the simplest method is to just echo prior to doing the command you'd like to do.

Example:
`cat <someinput> | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {}; <somecmd>;'`

`-I{}` sets `{}` to the current string being processed

`sh -c` will allow you to execute multiple commands (note: semi-colon after every command is required *including the last one*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pv` to monitor the pipe (not in terms of files though, since it sits in your pipe) but you would have to tell `pv` the size of the find output, which seems really cumbersome (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/343204)).

I would really recommend using `parallel`, based on what you are trying to accomplish...this is exactly what it was designed for.

Otherwise, if you have the Apple Developer Tools installed, you could write a small script that generates a Makefile to accomplish the same task and make sure it prints the progress in a way that you desire.